# Can't remap Swing key binding for "enter"

Tags: swing, scala, key-bindings

I'm using swing key-bindings in a scala program. I'm trying to capture key-input in a JPanel. For some reason I can't remap the enter-key. shift-enter works and other keys work as well. What is special about enter? Below is a code snippet from my JPanel:

```
val ADD_SIBLING_TO_SELECTED = "add-sibling-to-selected"
val enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift ENTER")//todo: figure out why plain enter does not work
getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).remove(enter)
getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(enter, ADD_SIBLING_TO_SELECTED)
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent
getActionMap().put(ADD_SIBLING_TO_SELECTED, new AbstractAction {
  override def actionPerformed(e: ActionEvent){
    println(ADD_SIBLING_TO_SELECTED)
  }
})
```

Comment: oops, "shift ENTER" is the one that works. If I remove the "shift", the action will not fire.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special to the ENTER as such, only happens to be the most used gesture for indicating "ready" :-) So there's a non-zero probability that the ENTER might be already bound somewhere else. One candidate could be a default button registered in the frame's rootpane. Also note that the WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW type binding is the very last to be queried.

CU
Jeanette

Comment: I was thinking that the event gets consumed somewhere upstream. My GUI is a little complicated with a couple splitters and some tab-panes. I tried adding enter-action handlers to the components that contain the problem-component, but so far I have not been able to get the enter-event to fire.

Answer (score 1):

Strange; that works on my machine. Tried it with this complete code on scala 2.8.1 on mac os x 10.6.7 with jdk 1.6.0_24:

```
object ShowKeyPress {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import javax.swing._
    val frame = new JFrame
    frame.setVisible(true)
    frame.add(new JPanel {
      val ADD_SIBLING_TO_SELECTED = "add-sibling-to-selected"
      val enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER")
      //todo: figure out why plain enter does not work
      getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).remove(enter)
      getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(enter, ADD_SIBLING_TO_SELECTED)

      import java.awt.event.ActionEvent

      getActionMap().put(ADD_SIBLING_TO_SELECTED, new AbstractAction {
        override def actionPerformed(e: ActionEvent) {
          println(ADD_SIBLING_TO_SELECTED)
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: your code works here too (almost same system, though, os x 10.6.4)

Comment: I'm using Scala 2.8.1 and 1.6.0_24 as well, but on windows 7. I can get the enter-event under different circumstances, but not for this component.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to call `requestFocusInWindow()` and use `WHEN_FOCUSED` and everything worked. I'm still not sure why shift-enter worked but enter did not. Thanks for the feedback!